# Pre action correspondence reciprocated and "fizzled out"

Tags: england-and-wales, civil-procedure, statute-of-limitations, pre-action-protocol

B unlawfully discriminates against C on January 1. C has 6 years under the limitations act 1980 to seek remedy under the equality act 2010. On march 5 he issues B a letter before claim requesting a response within 14 days. B responds on the twelfth day, march 17, essentially acknowledging their mistake and illegal conduct but asking C for sympathy and forgiveness but making no rebuttals to either the charges made or the quantum of the remedies sought, other than simply asking for sympathy and mercy. C becomes very busy and then ill, and is unable to further pursue the matter until 15 months later in the following year.

Where does the case now stand, and what is C's next step in pursuing this case, as he is still well within his statutory 6 year limitation period for bringing the claim?